# Case milestone conclusion by the user doesn't seem to trigger the process builder?

Tags: trigger, case, visual-workflow, casemilestone, order-of-execution

I'm working on a service system on which the case has a field called "observations". When the case's status change the system is supposed to copy its content to a big object related to the case record, and - as you might have guessed now - clear the contents of said field on the record.

While everything seems to work fine when I update the case using a flow (another field changes, then the flow's conditions update the status and save the record), I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work when I update the record using the case milestone functionality. I defined on the milestone actions a update action on said status field, but the functionality that does that process I described above is not triggered as expected.

On the case trigger, I have Apex code which handles the big object insertion (by verifying on `Trigger.oldMap` if the record status has changed and if the observation field is not `null`).

On the flow, I have the decision that checks whether the status was changed or not, to clear the field on an update action inside the flow. I'm doing this by calling it through process builder, and the flow receives both field values as arguments (new and old status values).

Comment: So the trigger works but the PB does not or neither of them works?

Comment: How are you closing the milestone? Is that through trigger?

Comment: @gNerb The trigger seems to work, yes. But not the process builder or the flow fired by it.

Comment: @SantanuBoral The milestone is being closed by that link on the "milestones" component.

Comment: Can you include more information about the PB and flow? Screenshots and what not? If the trigger does fire, I can only imagine the pb or flow fail due to some other reason.

Comment: PB fires every time the record is modified. It has conditions on two picklist fields to fire a flow (which contains the logic to clear the field or not). The PB works every time the update isn't fired by the milestone component link (the one "mark completed").